# join two query postgresql

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8

im trying mix two queries postgresql

```
select stock_quant.product_id as prod_id, product_product.name_template as name ,sum(stock_quant.qty) as qty_quant
from stock_quant
join product_product on stock_quant.product_id = product_product.id
join stock_location on stock_quant.location_id = stock_location.id
where stock_location.usage in ('internal','transit')
group by stock_quant.product_id, product_product.name_template
order by stock_quant.product_id
```

this one get me products with sum quantity in table stock_quant
,second query get me sum of quntity in an other table "stock_history"

```
select stock_history.product_id as prod_id,product_product.name_template as name , sum(stock_history.quantity) as qty_history
from stock_history
join product_product on stock_history.product_id = product_product.id
group by stock_history.product_id,name
order by stock_history.product_id
```

well , what im trying to do is to show only products which both sums are equal for same product ofc
thnx i really appreciate some explanations

Comment: well, if you would have provided the schema of the tables, it would have been good then.

Answer (score 0):

well the answer is :

```
select stock_quant.product_id as prod_id, product_product.name_template as name ,sum(stock_quant.qty) as qty_quant
from stock_quant
join product_product on stock_quant.product_id = product_product.id
join stock_location on stock_quant.location_id = stock_location.id
where stock_location.usage in ('internal','transit') 
group by stock_quant.product_id, product_product.name_template
having sum(stock_quant.qty) != (
    select sum(stock_history.quantity) as qty_history
    from stock_history
    where stock_quant.product_id = stock_history.product_id )
order by stock_quant.product_id
```

currently i'm at work , i'll provide you guys more explanations later if needed 
thnx